# RESTKIT: Request not send to server

Tags: iphone, restkit

I send request to the server but not execute successfully.

this is ny code:

```
RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:@"http://10.0.0.37:7070/TPServer/ws/feedback/"]; 

    RKParams *rkp = [RKParams params]; 
    [rkp setValue:@"ek367t27856vuth45tyv45th89" forParam:@"deviceid"]; 
    [rkp setValue:@"demo" forParam:@"source"]; 
    [rkp setValue:@"3.4" forParam:@"rating"]; 

    [client post:@"new" params:rkp delegate:self];
```

am i doing wrong???

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the parameters are sent successfully or not. If the parameters are sent successfully then i dont think so there is any problem with the code.

Comment: @CodemasterGabriel i am a bit new with IOS & restkit. i also send request without parameters but it did not work.. server wasn't getting my request.

Comment: Then i think so there is some firewall that is blocking the request as i can see that you are making a call to the local server. Please check the network configuration in this case both on your machine as well as the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like in restkit **v0.10.0** we can send data to server via NSDictionary.

But If we want to post data via multipart we can user:

```
RKParams *rkp = [RKParams params];
```

Data from the RKParams will send data to server's multipart section. So might possibility that server should not contain any simple Post section.